# DrawTextEx with DT_RIGHT truncates text

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

I'm using DrawTextEx to draw a string into a TCanvas but, when I set the DT_RIGHT flag and most of characters are "1" and the font is not fixed-width, (i.e.: "551111,111" with "Arial" font) the start position of the string is miscalculated and appears to be truncated on the last character (see image for detail).

[image]

Below a code snippet:

```
var
  dtPar: TDrawTextParams;  
  C: TCanvas; 
  R: TRect;
  Align: Integer; 

  ...

    dtPar.cbSize := SizeOf(dtPar);
    dtPar.iTabLength := 0;
    dtPar.iLeftMargin := 0;
    dtPar.iRightMargin := 0;
    dtPar.uiLengthDrawn := 0;

    Align := DT_NOPREFIX or DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_RIGHT or DT_WORDBREAK;

    DrawTextEx(C.Handle, PChar(FTextToDisplay), -1, R, Align, @dtPar)
```

I've tried on several Windows versions and I noticed that happens on Vista or later. It not occurs on XP.

I'm building using Delphi XE 3.

Comment: Are you sure the Rect values are within the **client** rect of the control on which you are drawing? For example: a control's border width differs considerably between different Windows versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the rectangle that you are passing to `DrawTextEx` extends beyond the right hand edge of the canvas.

Comment: The canvas "C" is bigger than the Rect "R" (the green area in the image initially posted) passed to the function.
Fact is that when I use a fixed-size font (i.e.: Courier New), the string is not truncated. 
I need to draw the string aligned to the right into the green rectangle, independently from the font used. How can I do?

Comment: The obvious explanation is as per my answer. If you are to supply an MCVE then we can examine more detail.

Comment: Your code performs just fine, with monospaced fonts as well as with proportional fonts. A Canvas has no size, so you can draw anywhere. Its representation is cropped by a window's or control's client boundary. When your Rect exceeds these bounds, then cut-off results can be expected.

Comment: It turns out it was just right the size of the rect exceeding the right edge of the canvas. The environment of my application is too messy to reproduce (kind of a report generator tool). The problem was related to a resizing/stretching of the canvas happening subsequently the call of "DrawTextEx" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call twice `DrawTextEx`.
The first time with `dwDTFormat = DT_CALCRECT` to obtain the value of the `TRect` structure in the `lprc` *in-out* parameter; the second time you can call it like you already do but passing the `TRect` obtained by the first call.
**Edit**
Obtain the width from the first call then reposition the rect before the second call to `DrawTextEx`

Comment: How would this help considering that `DT_RIGHT` is used?

Comment: What does the alignement with the size of the containing rect? I meant *get the size first then position the rect*

Comment: Normally you'd make the rectangle fill the width and by using `DT_RIGHT` have no need to ask for the required size. Just as when you wish to draw left aligned text.

Comment: I agree but this is a case when the size of the rectangle overflows the bound as you said in your answer, so either enlarge the canvas or move back the rect and in this case it's useful to known its width... or am I missing something?

Comment: No amount of `DT_CALCRECT` can get around the real problem.